# Install php-soap56w on CentOS 7 x64 not working

Tags: centos, php, yum, soap

I followed the guide located [here](http://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2010/install-apache-php-on-fedora-centos-red-hat-rhel/comment-page-3/) to install PHP 5.6 with Apache on CentOS 7.

Everything went along smoothly.

I now need to install PHP-SOAP and it's gave me dependancy conflicts. So I used [this guide here](https://webtatic.com/packages/php56/) to update my server repositories to include webtatic and it's now doing this:

```
$ yum --assumeyes install php56w-soap

Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile  
* Webmin: download.webmin.com  
* base: centos.mirror.uber.com.au  
* epel: epel.mirror.digitalpacific.com.au  
* extras: centos.mirror.crucial.com.au  
* updates: centos.mirror.crucial.com.au 
* webtatic: us-east.repo.webtatic.com Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php56w-soap.x86_64 0:5.6.2-1.w7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php56w-common(x86-64) = 5.6.2-1.w7 for package: php56w-soap-5.6.2-1.w7.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php56w-common.x86_64 0:5.6.2-1.w7 will be installed Removing php56w-common.x86_64 0:5.6.2-1.w7 - u due to obsoletes from installed php-common-5.6.4-2.el7.remi.x86_64
--> Restarting Dependency Resolution with new changes.
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php56w-common.x86_64 0:5.6.2-1.w7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php56w-common(x86-64) = 5.6.2-1.w7 for package: php56w-soap-5.6.2-1.w7.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution Error: Package: php56w-soap-5.6.2-1.w7.x86_64 (webtatic)
       Requires: php56w-common(x86-64) = 5.6.2-1.w7
       Available: php56w-common-5.6.0-1.w7.x86_64 (webtatic)
           php56w-common(x86-64) = 5.6.0-1.w7
       Available: php56w-common-5.6.0-2.w7.x86_64 (webtatic)
           php56w-common(x86-64) = 5.6.0-2.w7
       Available: php56w-common-5.6.1-1.w7.x86_64 (webtatic)
           php56w-common(x86-64) = 5.6.1-1.w7  
You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem  
You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

I have tried with both the `--skip-broken` and the `rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest` workarounds and both to no avail.

Is there anything else that I can do to get this off the ground?

My currently installed version of PHP was 5.4.10 then it got downgraded to 5.4.6. I cannot go lower than 5.4.6 for compliance purposes, but I now do need PHP-SOAP to be installed.

Is there something I'm possibly overlooking or missing?

Comment: [Administration panels are off topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). [Even the presence of an administration panel on a system,](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/6538/118258) because they [take over the systems in strange and non-standard ways, making it difficult or even impossible for actual system administrators to manage the servers normally](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3924/118258), and tend to indicate low-quality questions from *users* with insufficient knowledge for this site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be confused as to what version of PHP is installed on your system *now*, so let's start there.

First, you have PHP 5.6.4 installed, from the remi-php56 repository, not PHP 5.4.6. You should have no issues installing `php-soap` from remi-php56, presuming you remembered to enable the remi and remi-php56 repos. Since they appear to be disabled, that is almost certainly the cause of the problem.

There's no need to add webtatic here, and the cause of this error is that the webtatic packages conflict with the remi packages. You should remove the webtatic repo, enable the remi and remi-php56 repos, and then install php-soap.

(Remi's high quality packages over the years helped him become an official Fedora packager and become employed at Red Hat. I don't know who the webtatic people are, but I have never been impressed by the quality of their packages.)

Comment: I'm going to zip through the setup again and follow your guidelines to see how this works out for me. I'll let you know shortly. Thank you in advance for providing some insight. :-)

Comment: This might seem a silly question, but where do I enable the remi-php56 repo from?

I found the information available on the Remi blog here -> http://blog.famillecollet.com/post/2014/03/02/New-repository-remi-php56

But it's not showing me where the download link for it is?

Comment: @DanijelJ You should already have `/etc/yum.repos.d/remi.repo`. If you don't, then install the `remi-release` RPM from his web site.

Comment: OK. I just realised how dumb that last question was. I re-read the post again and realised I need to do the following: `yum --enablerepo=remi,remi-php56 --assumeyes install php-soap` .... it now works. Thank you so so much! You're a life saver!

Comment: @DanijelJ I would still edit the repo file and make sure they are persistently enabled. Otherwise you (or your successor) will be confused the next time you need to add or update a PHP package.